# Order List By Date, Id and Parent Id (Guid)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List with ID, Parent_ID and Date and I want to order it in C# with linq an OrderBy()

| ID | Parent_ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Guid1 | null | 13.05.22 |
| Guid2 | null | 16.05.22 |
| Guid3 | Guid1 | 17.05.22 |
| Guid4 | Guid1 | 18.05.22 |
| Guid5 | Guid2 | 20.05.22 |

Now I need to order the List. The current Date should be at top but I need to group it by the ID and Parent_ID.
The List should look like following.

| ID | Parent_ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Guid2 | null | 16.05.22 |
| Guid5 | Guid2 | 20.05.22 |
| Guid1 | null | 13.05.22 |
| Guid3 | Guid1 | 17.05.22 |
| Guid4 | Guid1 | 18.05.22 |

EDIT

This is my code

```
List<MyModel> items = myList
                    .Select(s => new MyModel
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        ParentId = s.ParentId,
                        Date = s.Date
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Parent_Id == null)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Parent_Id)
                    .ToList();
```

MyModel

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Some Values

```
var myList = new List<MyModel>
{
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("EDDC393F2D304C97B7BA744AE75A13B1"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2007, 12, 10) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("99F31A6397C04A5A9334275660F2614D"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2018, 01, 10) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("19F31A6397C04A5A9334275660F2614B"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2022, 05, 13) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("10BB917E50344DAD8D09FA2F3ACDFD12"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2022, 05, 16) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ParentId = Guid.Parse("19F31A6397C04A5A9334275660F2614B"), Date = new DateTime(2022, 05, 17) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ParentId = Guid.Parse("19F31A6397C04A5A9334275660F2614B"), Date = new DateTime(2022, 05, 18) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ParentId = Guid.Parse("10BB917E50344DAD8D09FA2F3ACDFD12"), Date = new DateTime(2022, 05, 20) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("A9F31A6397C04A5A9334275660F2614C"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2019, 05, 20) },
    new MyModel {Id = Guid.Parse("00000233010247B99282C151931FF6C6"), ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2011, 06, 05) },
};
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: What do you mean by "group by Id and Parent Id"? All of your Id values are unique. What are you actually ordering by, because the Id values are not in order, and the Date values are not in order?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the documentation on the `GroupBy`, `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` LINQ methods?

Comment: please post an example where we can see the ordering effect of each column. Really cool would be if you would go through the effort of posting a class with 3 properties, make a list and populate the list with the proper entities and proper values for the properties. So that we could copy it and paste it into our IDE. This way we would be really fast in comparing our result to the expected outcome from your question.

Comment: I wrote some more Infos :-)

Comment: So, basically your table is a flattened tree? Where you have the parent, then underneath the parent you have it's children ordered by CreationDate descending? Then the next parent and all it's children ordered by CreationDate descending? etc, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

I tyred the following code. But it is really slow if the Data amount is big.

```
var newList = new List<MyModel>();

            foreach (var item in myList.Where(w => w.ParentId == null).OrderByDescending(o => o.Date))
            {
                newList.Add(item);

                var subList = myList.Where(w => w.ParentId == item.Id).OrderByDescending(o => o.Date);

                foreach (var sub in subList)
                {
                    newList.Add(sub);
                }
            }
```

But this is how it should look like

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible to write an simple linq statement with orderBy like I need. I use now the foreach and filter the Date to the current year. So I have less amount of data and the loading time is really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to sort it:

```
var lookup = myList.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

IEnumerable<MyModel> Sort(Guid? parentId) =>
    lookup[parentId]
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
        .SelectMany(x => Sort(x.Id).StartWith(x));
    
var newList = Sort(null).ToList();
```

Given the data from the question, I get this:

[image: newList]